# Adobe Animate: Export SVG seqence

Tags: svg, adobe-flash, adobe-animate

I want to export a svg sequence in animate, however I can only find tutorials / info on how to export animated svgs. The latter is not usable in the project we are currently doing and right now it seems like the only option is going through the whole animation and exporting each frame as an svg which is kind of time-consuming as you can imagine ...

Does anyone now a script / plug-in that may let me export as svg sequence?
Or maybe another tool that lets me "convert" an animated svg into a svg sequence?